# starting predictionio vendor'd hbase when zookeeper is already running

Tags: predictionio

I've installed the quickstart version of the prediction.io stack on a system that already has zookeeper installed and running. When I run `pio-start-all` it fails with the message:

```
Could not start ZK at requested port of 2181.  ZK was started at port: -1.  Aborting as clients (e.g. shell) will not be able to find this ZK quorum.
Waiting 10 seconds for HBase to fully initialize...
```

Running `pio status` confirms that hbase is not running.

I've attempted to start hbase [according to the FAQ](https://docs.prediction.io/resources/faq/) but get the same error.

I don't see anything in the pio-env.sh to disable starting zookeeper when starting up hbase. Is there a way to initialize hbase without also starting zookeeper?

Answer (score 0):

Using existing ZooKeeper ensemble: http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/zookeeper.html#d1984e11388